# How do I give content box and embedded objects minimum heights?

Tags: html, css, pdf, height, embed

I'm working on making a personal website for a web design class, and I am having difficulty with content boxes maintaining a standard height and not letting any embedded information that is larger in height stretch the content box. This is what it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT65a.png

Ideally, I want the height of the content box to change with the height of the pdf.  However, I also need it to remain reflexive. I have included the css for the area where the PDF is, and the html of the entire page in case there is a part I am not changing and should be.

```
article {
background-color:#fff;
float:none;
padding-top:10px;
padding-right:5%;
padding-left:5%;
padding-bottom:10px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:10px;
border: 1px solid #5A5333; 
width:96%;
}

article {
    overflow:hidden;
    display: table-cell;
    }

article {
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">

<title>Stephanie Newman's Portfolio Website</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="resume.css" />

<!-- [if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- [if lt IE 8]> 
<style> /* For IE < 8 (trigger hasLayout) */ .clearfix {zoom:1;} </style> 
<![endif]-->


</head>

<body>
<div>
<header>
<img class="logo" src="_images/logo.png" alt="index logo">
<h1>Stephanie Newman</h1>
</header>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="biography.html">Biography</a></li>
<li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<section class="clearfix">
<article>
If you can't view the pdf below or would like to download a copy of my resume, you can <a href="/StephanieNewmanResume.pdf">click here</a> to download the PDF file.
<br>
<object data="/StephanieNewmanResume.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" internalinstanceid="15">...</object>
</article>
</section>


<footer>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="biography.html">Biography</a></li>
<li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<p class="footer"> Website &copy; 2015 by Stephanie Newman. Background &copy; 2014 by Sagive on subtlepatterns.com. 
Contact: <a href="mailto:steph1230@ufl.edu">
steph1230@ufl.edu</a></p>
</footer>
</div><!--Closes container div-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: P.S! Please remove the email address from your sample code (if the address is a valid one)

Comment: ... and remove the phone number, too!

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally, I want the height of the content box to change with the height of the pdf.

If you want to have your box as a % of the PDF page, be careful that some units, like vh and vw, are relative to the viewport dimensions, so you have to declare **two** stylesheets: one for the screen and the other one for the paper/PDF.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/ for a list of the units you can use.